# What is the correct way to destroy an element created with Renderer2?

Tags: angular

In our code base we have a virtual repeat directive that uses Renderer2 to create a div like this:

```
this.renderer2.createElement('div');
```

In the ngOnDestroy method we are destroying it like this:

```
this.renderer.destroyNode(this.offsetBeforeEl);
```

This worked fine and we had no issues until we built the application in prod mode and we started getting the following error:

```
main.js?d73b003…:formatted:87193 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.renderer.destroyNode is not a function
```

I added a breakpoint to the that line and found that in fact destroyNode is not a method on Renderer2.  I went to the source code for angular and found the comment above the method in the abstract class defintion:

```
/**
   * This property is allowed to be null / undefined,
   * in which case the view engine won't call it.
   * This is used as a performance optimization for production mode.
   */
  destroyNode: ((node: any) => void)|null;
```

So I checked out the code for the view and saw this:

```
if (view.renderer.destroyNode) {
  destroyViewNodes(view);
}
if (isComponentView(view)) {
  view.renderer.destroy();
}
```

If I can't rely on this method existing, what is the correct way to destroy a node that was dynamically created using Renderer2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `renderer.removeChild` method.

> until we built the application in prod mode

`destroyNode` method is defined on the [DebugRenderer2](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/services.ts#L625) which is not used in the production mode.

The correct way to handle node removal can be inferred from the way angular does it, for example this [execRenderNodeAction](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/util.ts#L356) function:

```
function execRenderNodeAction(
    view: ViewData, renderNode: any, action: RenderNodeAction, parentNode: any, nextSibling: any,
    target?: any[]) {
  const renderer = view.renderer;
  switch (action) {
    case RenderNodeAction.RemoveChild:
      renderer.removeChild(parentNode, renderNode);
      break;
```

So, use `removeChild` like this:

```
    const parent = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const child = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.appendChild(parent, child);

    // using remove child
    this.renderer.removeChild(parent, child);
```

Comment: it doesn't remove the child properly! this causes endless loop:  while (child = parent.lastChild) { this.renderer.removeChild(parent, child); }

Comment: @NextDeveloper, can you make a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: @NextDeveloper the renderer doesn't actually update the DOM as you do this, so you need to do something like my answer

Answer (score 9):

To remove all children you can must iterate over the child elements. 
Note that `children` isn't a true array so it must be converted first.

```
        Array.from(this.elementRef.nativeElement.children).forEach(child => {
            console.log('children.length=' + this.elementRef.nativeElement.children.length);
            this.renderer.removeChild(this.elementRef.nativeElement, child);
       });
```

The logging statement demonstrates that the children aren't actually removed in 'real time' from the DOM - which is why a while loop doesn't work to remove `lastChild`.

Use caution if these elements weren't originally added by you - because if they're components you may get memory leaks or all kinds of weirdness. The above was only tested for elements I'd added myself to an empty element node.

I thought I should be able to do `[...this.elementRef.nativeElement.children]`, but this complained that `slice` doesn't exist - so I just reverted to `Array.from`.